# Try to submit a form to server in json form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I'm a beginner to Jquery. Now I'm trying to submit a form(post) to server and the form will be processed by server. Here is my form code:

```
<form name="broadcastform" id="broadcastform" method="post" action="">  


        <h1 id="broadcast_title" style="color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);font-size: 250%;font-weight: 400;margin-top:-10px" align="middle">BROADCAST</h1>
        <hr style="border-color:#ffffff;weight:40%;margin:0 auto;margin-bottom:20px">
        <center class="page_intro">
        <div style="margin-top:-1%;color:rgba(255,255,255,0.7);width:90%;margin-bottom:12.5%" class="page_intro">
        <font size="6" style="line-height: 150%"class="page_intro"><center>Welcome!</center></font>
        <font size="5" style=" padding-top:20px;line-height: 150%;font-weight:normal;opacity:0.7"class="page_intro"><center>This is a Tool to Configure and Broadcast Your Modulator. Please Follow the Steps and Fill in the Parameter Fields for Your Preference. Enjoy the Tour !</center></font>
        </div>
        </center>
        <!-- Page Basic Setting --> 
        <select name="InputSource"  class="required page_basic" style="margin-left:23%" form="broadcastform" >

                    <option value="">Broadcast Input</option>             
                    <option value="0">HDMIPhy</option>             
                    <option value="1">USB Streaming</option>             
                    <option value="2">MPEC-TS Interface</option>             
                    <option value="3">VIP(Ethernet)</option>         
        </select>
        <select name="ModulationMode"class= "page_basic required" style="margin-left:23%" form="broadcastform">             
                    <option value="">Modulation Mode</option>             
                    <option value="1">ATSC</option>             
                    <option value="2">DTMB</option>             
                    <option value="3">DVB</option>             
                    <option value="4">ISDB</option>         
        </select>           
        <input type= "text" name= "ProviderName" placeholder="Provider Name" maxlength="16" class="required page_basic">      
        <input type= "text" name= "ServiceName" placeholder="Service Name" maxlength="16" class="required page_basic" style="margin-bottom:8%">

        <!-- Page IP Setting. Only with ETH Input Source--> 
        <input type= "text" name= "LocalIP" class="page_ip" placeholder="Local IP" style="margin-top:30px"  id="LocalIp">             
        <input type= "text" name= "RemoteVIPAddr" class="page_ip" style="margin-top:7%" placeholder="Remote VIP Address" id="RemoteIp">
        <input type= "text" name= "RemoteVIPPort" class="page_ip" style="margin-top:7%;margin-bottom:11.8%"  placeholder="Remote VIP Port"id="RemoteVIPPort">

        <!-- Page RF Setting -->              
        <input type= "text" name= "RFOutFreq" class="page_rf" style="margin-top:7%" placeholder="RF Output Frequency"  id="RFOutFreq">
        <input type= "text" name= "RFIfFreq" class="page_rf"style="margin-top:7%" placeholder="RF IF Frequency" id="RFIfFreq">         
        <input type= "text" name= "RFBandwidth" class="page_rf" style="margin-top:7%;margin-bottom:11.8%" placeholder="RF Bandwidth" id="RFBandwidth">   

        <!-- Page EncryptKey Setting -->              
        <input type= "text" name= "EncryptKeyLo" class="page_encrypt" style= "margin-top:13%" placeholder="Encrypt Key Low" id="EncryptKeyLo">  
        <input type= "text" name= "EncryptKeyHi" class="page_encrypt" style=" margin-top:13%;margin-bottom:16.1%" placeholder="Encrypt Key High" id="EncryptKeyHi">
</form>
```

And this is my Jquery ajax code to submit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // click on button submit
        $("#submit").on('click', function(){
            // send ajax
            $.ajax({
                url: '192.168.0.10', // url where to submit the request
                type : "POST", // type of action POST || GET
                dataType : 'json', // data type
                data : $("#broadcastform").serialize(), // post data || get data
                success : function(result) {
                    // you can see the result from the console
                    // tab of the developer tools
                    console.log(result);
                },
                error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
                    console.log(xhr, resp, text);
                }
            })
        });
    });
```

I try,

```
var result = $('form').serializeArray();
var j = $('#result').text(JSON.stringify(result))
```

[image]

The form in json seems right but somehow when it send to server, the server still get "x-www-form-urlencoded" data. What did I do wrong?
And also, is it possible to see the data string I submitted when I'm testing in local ip?

Comment: use `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the `form` element is still being submit normally, so your AJAX request doesn't complete.

To fix this, hook to the `submit` event of the form, and call `preventDefault()` on the event raised. Try this:

```
$("#broadcastform").on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '192.168.0.10',
        type : "POST",
        dataType : 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success : function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function(xhr, resp, text) {
            console.log(xhr, resp, text);
        }
    })
});
```

You may also want to double check the URL you're sending to. It looks like you would need to include the protocol if you're using an absolute URL, or make it relative instead.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just wondering is it possible to see the data that form submit when i click the submit button?

Comment: As to the url. Because Im now trying to build a web server on the stm32 MCU. So there will be only 2 ip in the network. So i think it alright i just use the absolute URL?

Comment: Yes, assign `$(this).serialize()` to a variable and use `console.log()` to see it. Re. the URL using an IP address is fine, my point is you would need to add the protocol (ie. `http://192.168.0.10/foo.html`) or make the URL relative (ie. `/foo.html`)

Comment: You mean i gon put console.log($(this).serialize()) in "succes :"?

Comment: i just dont know why if i hook the submit. it do nothing when i click it.

Comment: <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn inner"/> this is my submit code

Comment: I don't have enough information here to help you. The code in my answer should work fine, so all I can suggest is that you check the console for errors.